# Quem atribui meu ip?

Tags: linux, windows, mac, internet

Eu poderia ter meu próprio ip? Se sim como? Quem diz que meu computador possui um ip, é o provedor de internet ou Dhcp? Ou ainda é o Adaptador de rede,  Netbios, 
ou Mac Address?  Roteador? Ou protocolo TC/IP ?

Answer (score 1):

É sempre o servidor DHCP. A questão é que como a internet é uma rede, existem várias camadas que podem alterar isso. Por ex. se seu pc está ligado direto no modem, o DHCP do seu provedor vai te dar o seu IP, se houver um roteador no meio do caminho (e isso vale tbm para os que tbm são modems) então o roteador tbm tem um pequeno servidor DHCP e ele vai criar outra rede interna e te dar um IP dessa rede (e pra internet, todos os PC's dessa subrede têm o mesmo IP).

Normalmente os provedores disponibilizam pra clientes residenciais endereços IP dinâmicos, ou seja, seu IP muda com o tempo na internet, mas normalmente vc pode pedir IP estático como um serviço a mais junto ao seu provedor, e óbvio, por um preço.

Comment: Nem sempre é o DHCP... Podemos desativar e inserir manualmente qualquer IP mesmo que fora de zona

Answer (score 0):

> Eu poderia ter meu próprio ip?

Sim.

> Se sim como?

[Solicitar IP](https://registro.br/tecnologia/provedor-acesso.html?secao=numeracao#!#solicitar)

> Quem diz que meu computador possui um ip, é o provedor de internet ou Dhcp?

Quando você contrata um provedor, este define um IP para seu roteador, este IP poderá ser dinâmico ou estático.

Comment: Negativos são bem vindos, ainda mais se acompanhados de uma explicação proporcionando a todos algum tipo de conhecimento. Mas no geral poucos são capazes de oferecer isso através do negativo...

Comment: Deve ter sido por causa do link que você colocou. Esse link não faz sentido para quem só quer um ou outro ip fixo. Parece que você está sendo sarcástico.

Comment: De modo algum... No caso vamos dizer que "ai seria a raiz", claro que pode solicitar um no ISP tmb...Mas faz parte... Só acho interessante saber usar o negativo, embora não exista um consenso, ao meu ver  é elegante dizer o por que do negativo, que como mencionei ajuda não só a mim que respondi, mas a todos no geral.

Comment: E ainda assim não está errada minha resposta(é uma das opções), pelo menos essa parte...